# Не получается урезать ось Х на графике. Пробовала через xlim программа не принимает. Что я делаю не так?

Tags: r, ggplot2

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat_works,aes(`Медиана пребывания сотрудников`, `Уровень удовлетворенности`),xlim=c(0,10)) + geom_col(mapping = NULL, data = NULL)

Хотелось бы отбросить значения после 10 на оси Х,чтобы диаграмма имела более презентабельный вид.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто укажите xlim() отдельным слоем. Как [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606697/how-to-set-limits-for-axes-in-ggplot2-r-plots).

Comment: Cпасибо большое!